# How to write a file in a mac machine from an ios application using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to mobile app development.

I have a hybrid application that uses objective C code also for printer integration. Its running on an iOS device.

Now I need to create a file and write into it while the app is running. The file must be in a particular machine(say my local Mac machine) and not created in the sandbox of my application. This is mainly because at a later point I need to open the file and view it locally.

How do I do this.

Please help as soon as possible.

Comment: i don't think apple allow you to write outside of sandbox.. best you can in ios is write in temp folder of ios device... use web (may be localhost) to write to your mac

Comment: You will need some app or service running on the Mac and have your app connect to that over the network

Comment: Look at iCloud docs for a possible option.